# where is the DCT matrix in Libjpeg?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, libjpeg, dct

In libjpeg I am unable to locate the 8x8 DCT matrix ? If I am not wrong this matrix is always a constant for a 8x8 block .  it must contain 1/sqrt(8) on the first row but where is this matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an actual JPEG implementation, the DCT matrix is usually factored down to its Gaussian Normal Form. That gives a series of matrix multiplications. However, in the normal form, these only involve operations on the diagonal and values adjacent to the diagonal. Most of the values in the normalized matrices are zero so you can omit them.

That transforms the DCT into a series of 8 parallel operations.

This book describes a couple of ways the matrix operations can be transformed:

[http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)

This book describes a tensor approach that is theoretically more efficient but tends not to be so in implementation

[http://www.amazon.com/JPEG-Compression-Standard-Multimedia-Standards/dp/0442012721/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0442012721)

Comment: Hi, I have a c library that provides specialised DSP functions such as matrix multiplication .can I write my own matrix and use it in that place .

Comment: In theory you could but Libjpeg code tends to be convoluted. You might have a problem getting it in. Plus, libJpeg might combine the quantization and DCT process. The problem is matrix multiplication is not a very efficient way to do these transforms (unless you factor and omit the multiply by zero operations).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. Or maybe it's somewhere in a sneaky place, but it doesn't really matter. Real implementations of DCT don't work that way, they're very specialized pieces of code that have all the constants hardcoded into them, and they look nothing like a matrix multiplication. It is occasionally useful to view the transform as a matrix multiplication from a theoretical standpoint, but it can be implemented much more efficiently.

For the DCT in libjpeg, see for example the file jfdctflt.c (or one of its friends).